# java hibernate tomcat configuration - Session will not be opened

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to configure hibernate and tomcat, so that tomcat will manage the database conections, but I am getting some errors. 
Could you help? Here is my code: 

Here is the HibernateUtil

```
public class HibernateUtil {  
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();  

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {  
    try {  
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml  
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  

    } catch (Throwable ex) {  
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed  
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);  
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);  
    }  
}  

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {  
    return sessionFactory;  
}  

public static void shutdown() {  
    // Close caches and connection pools  
    getSessionFactory().close();  
}  
}
```

HibernateListener:

```
public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener {

/*  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); // Just call the static initializer
                                        // of that class
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close(); // Free all resources
}
}*/

@Override  
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  
    System.out.println("\n\tInside contextInitialized()\n")
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  
    session.beginTransaction();  
}  

@Override  
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  

    HibernateUtil.shutdown();         
}  
}
```

I have also made an entry in web.xml

```
  <listener>
<listener-class>hibernate.HibernateListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I have created a jsp file and try to run a piece of code, which is:

```
public Employee getEmployeeByLogin(String login){
    Employee p= null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from employee p where p.login = '" + login +"'");
    p = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
    return p;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is   not valid without active transaction
```

I tried to do it similar way as described in https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingHibernateWithTomcat# but without success....
So once again. Please help.

Comment: Begin a transaction with the `Session`.

Comment: Time to go to bed... So easy. Thanks a lot:)